# if then statement within expect script

Tags: if-statement, expect

So I am attempting to scp a file to a drive from several local computers. However, not all of those computers have connected to this server before. So sometimes a machine will just prompt for a password when it has previously connected, other times a machine will warn of the key fingerprint. I have the script so far for sending the scp, I just need help with the variable. So apparently my post wasn't clear enough. Here is what I have so far.

This is my expect

```
set timeout -1
spawn ./transfer
match_max 100000
expect -exact "\rThe authenticity of host '192.168.255.255 (192.168.255.255)' can't be established.\r
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:jkladfsjklfjklfjklfjklfjklfdsjklfdsjkldfsjkl;fds\r
This key is not known by any other names\r
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/\[fingerprint\])? "
send -- "yes\r"
expect -exact "yes\r
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.255.255' (ED234234) to the list of known hosts.\r\r
\r(admin@192.168.255.255) Password:"
send -- "123456\r"
expect eof
```

"autoexpect" 57L, 2242B

Some machines will already have the network server added. So the expect "the authenticity of the host" will fail because it will just ask for a password.
I'm trying to figure out how to put into expect an if, then that looks for the "the authentcitiy" prompt OR just a password.

I found a post that said you can group the two expects together and whichever one it gets it will push the appropriate response? but I'm not sure how to format that properly. How do I group the expects so that the script doesn't get confused if it is never prompted for the "The authenticity of host".

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

The `expect` command can take multiple patterns you can watch for in parallel:

```
spawn ./transfer
expect {
    "Are you sure you want to continue connecting " {
        send -- "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "Password:" {
        send -- "123456\r"
    }
}
expect eof
```

The `exp_continue` "loops" back to the same expect statement, so it can continue to wait for one of the patterns.

The "Password" block does *not* continue, so after sending the password, the expect command ends, and then you wait for the process to end.